# How is FireSheep able to open devices in promiscuous mode?

Tags: networking, cookies, wireless, session-cookies, pcap

[FireSheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) is able to use [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) in promiscuous mode to listen to other computers on the network.  But promiscous mode requires root privileges, or at least access to /dev/bpf* on *nix machines.  How is this done?  Do Firefox extensions run with root privs?

Comment: Firesheep is for OS X and Windows only. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has run_privileged methods which run the required operations as root using OS-specific mechanisms such as [`AuthorizationCreate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AuthorizationCreate) ([OS X](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/blob/master/backend/src/osx_platform.cpp)), [`pkexec`](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/polkit/pkexec.1.html) ([Linux](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/blob/master/backend/src/linux_platform.cpp)) (but this is apparently not supported, yet), and of course `return true` on [Windows](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/blob/master/backend/src/windows_platform.cpp) (since pretty much everyone [runs as admin](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/commit/14f903f08ea6b26b4e7cf51d644a0a9c97205dbe) anyway).

Comment: hmmm, so those mechanisms must allow a subset of features that root would normally have, correct?  for example, in this case AuthorizationCreate would allow putting the device into promiscuous mode, but it would not allow removing /etc/passwd or something

Comment: @Caleb, nope.  After the `AuthorizationCreate` call, it calls [`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000826-CH1g-F17554), which will "with root privileges regardless of the privileges of the invoking process."  `pkexec` is an executable, rather than a function, and it can let you run as any user.  But it's also being used to request root in this case.  Keep in mind that both mechanisms will usually prompt the user.